# How does the Windows add/remove programs list get populated?

Tags: windows, installation

Just out of curiosity: how does the Windows add/remove programs list get populated?
Is it because most/all common installation wrappers set one or more specific registry keys?

Answer (score 3):

you are right, the information which programs are installed and how they can be deinstalled is mainly derived from the registry elements saved here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what others have already said, other registry locations where some additional installed can be found are:

HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

and as already mentioned before

HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of these registry answers are really just work arounds to this.  The problem here is that if you look at all of these keys you will have hundreds of unused values and duplicates as well as bunch of software that is no longer installed.  I for instance have over 900 keys in all 3 of these registry entries and only 229 entries in add or remove programs (yea I've got a lot of software).

So I did some experimentation adding and deleting keys. So there are are some rules I've found:

1. To show up an app must have a DisplayName Value under its key.\
2. The App must not have a SystemComponent Dword value of 1.
3. Duplicates are allowed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).