# Programs and Features

Tags: windows, uninstall

Where does Programs and Features get the data to populate the list of programs available to uninstall, and the data needed to do the actual uninstall?

I have an Autodesk program that shows a GUID in the Uninstall section of the registry, and running MSIExec.exe /x with that GUID does work, but the program is still listed in Programs and Features after the fact. I can uninstall manually, but as one of literally hundreds of ADSK programs and components, I really need to automate it. Sadly, ADSK support is utterly useless. I doubt if they even really understand the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Windows add/remove programs list get populated?](https://superuser.com/questions/448473/how-does-the-windows-add-remove-programs-list-get-populated)

Comment: It sounds like you should reinstall the ADSK programs, if you are unable to remove the ADSK programs, through Add/Remove.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx  . What do you have in ``HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[guid_of_your_app]\UninstallString``?

Comment: @user996142 The uninstall string they are providing is problematic, as it references something in an install cache that can be deleted. All their other components use a proper GUID. Pretty sure it's just ADSK being incompetent as usual, but I wanted to verify that the manual uninstall via Programs and Features really is using whatever uninstall the vendor provides.